function with 3 axes of symmetry
Is there a real-valued function $f:A\to\mathbb{R}$ where $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ whose graph has exactly 3 axes of symmetry? I haven't found an example, so I think there cannot exist such a function, but I need a hint to prove it.

Can you think of an example of such a function with the set $A$ as well as the graph consisting of exactly six points? Say, with the six points at "ten to one", "ten to five", "ten to nine", "ten pas three", "ten past seven" and "ten past eleven" on the face of 12 hour clock.

@JyrkiLahtonen Thank you! I've actually found an easier solution which I have overlooked. Let $A={0,\pm 1}$, define $f(\pm 1)=0$ and $f(0)=\sqrt{3}$. It's just the vertices of an equilateral triangle.

That's a good one. Feel free to post it as an answer :-)

Let $A=\{0,\pm 1\}$. Define our function to be $f(\pm 1)=0$ and $f(0)=\sqrt{3}$. Then its graph is the vertices of an equilateral triangle, fulfilling the conditions.
